# memcpy into a vector<wchar_t> from raw memory location

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, memcpy, wstring

I'm working with an API that provides, in memory, the memory address and length of strings of interest.  I'd like to read these strings into friendlier objects like wstring.

For smaller strings, a statically sized buffer works fine using the following code:

```
// This code works (but may have other issues)
// _stringLengthOffset and _bufferOffset are provided earlier by the API
// stringOID is the memory location of the string (and in terms of the API, the ObjectID)
DWORD stringLength;
memcpy(&stringLength, ((const void *)(stringOID + _stringLengthOffset)), sizeof(DWORD));
wchar_t argString[DEFAULT_ARGVALUE_BUFFER_SIZE];
memcpy(argString, ((const void *)(stringOID + _bufferOffset)), (stringLength) * sizeof(wchar_t));
argString[stringLength] = L'\0';  // Strings are not null terminated in memory
wstring argumentValue = argString;
```

I don't think it is a good idea to create a very, very large statically sized buffer (20,000 characters or more are possible with these strings.) I've tried several different approaches and this code seems close but does NOT work.

```
// This code does NOT work. 
vector<wchar_t> buffer;
buffer.reserve( stringLength + 1 );
memcpy( &buffer[0], (const void *)(stringOID + _bufferOffset), (stringLength) * sizeof(wchar_t) );
buffer.push_back( L'\0' );
buffer.shrink_to_fit();
wstring argumentValue( buffer.begin(), buffer.end() );
```

**Question: If the goal is creating a wstring, how does one correctly copy from raw memory (as provided by this particular API) into a dynamically sized buffer and then create a wstring?** 
(*Apologies if this has been answered before, as it seems like something someone before me would have asked but I was unable to find an appropriate question/answer with a few hours of searching.*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of ways.

1) Use resize instead of reserve and do the memcpy.  also get rid of the shrink fit.

2) Assign directly to the string:

```
const wchar_t* pstr = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(stringOID + _bufferOffset);
wstring s(pstr, pstr + stringLength);
// or:
wstring s(pstr, stringLength);
```

option 2) avoids a copy and additionally initialization of the resized vector.

Comment: Thanks! This worked.  As an aside, is there much benefit to memcpy to a statically sized buffer vs. just always using "wstring s(pstr, stringLength);"?  I'm guessing no with modern compilers since we're going to use a wstring in the end anyways.

Comment: Essentially the wstring construction will be taking a copy of the data so copying to an intermediate array is wasted effort.
memcpy'ing directly into uninitialized memory as an operation in itself may be faster than constructing a string with a wchar_t* depending upon the implementation of std::basic_string (i.e. if it uses memcpy internally for POD character types or not).  memcpy tends to be highly optimized (e.g. using SIMD instructions or block move instructions).  Additionally you pay for allocating the wstring's internal buffer in the heap which is slower than stack allocation.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much unless this code is performance critical.  In general only a tiny fraction of your program will have any affect on overall performance if optimized.

Comment: the constructor is almost certainly calling wsccpy in it's implementation which is basically memcpy

Comment: @cppguy looks like on msvc2008 after a substantial number of checks and balances it does eventually call wmemcpy_s

Answer (score 2):

```
std::wstring foo (somebuffer, charactercount);
```

reserve doesn't make a vector x wchar_t's long. it just preallocates. the vector still thinks it has 0 items inside. when you call push_back the vector now contains 1 character. shrink_to_fit will leave it at 1 character. memcpy is unable to tell the vector how long it will be after the copy. I'd recommend using the answer above but if you're hell bent on using a vector, it's resize, not reserve. and don't do the +1. That will be handled in the push_back.

Comment: With your code, what is the behavior if `somebuffer` gets deallocated? What is the state of `foo`?

Comment: foo contains a null terminated copy created in the constructor

Comment: What about COW and all that stuff then? Is COW only for when copying from an existing other `std::wstring`?

Comment: Copy on write is just a term to describe how std::wstring MAY be implemented (it isn't cow on windows). It's also not relevant. It's only relevant when assigning one wstring with another wstring. Internally it COULD have logic to not do a real copy until you try to modify the destination string but this is a copy from a raw buffer. It HAS to make a copy on construction.

Comment: @Mic: (and cppguy) COW is not permitted in string implementations starting in C++11, so not an issue.